# How can I add some strings to a list that already exists in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
input_list = ['5', '6']
```

the output I want is:

```
print(list1)
>> ['1','2','3','4','5']
>> ['1','2','3','4','6']
```

I tried many other things, but I couldn't get the result I want..
I also searched other Q&As to find the way, but I couldn't find as well..
Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's `extend` and `+=`. One is a function, the other a compound operator, respectively.

Comment: Could you explain it more specifically?

Comment: `list1.extend(input_list)`. Read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: @Kristine `list1.extend(input_list)`.

Comment: A solution can be found with a simple google search

Comment: @Kristine As suggested, read the documentation

Comment: Actually, my thing is this : input_list = ['a1', 'a2'] and what I did is this : new_1 = list1 + list(input_list[0])........it separates 'a1' to 'a', '1'.....how can I solve it..

Answer (score 2):

You can just concatenate two lists by adding them `[1,2]+[3]` will result in `[1,2,3]` you can use the extend or append methods as well

Answer (score 1):

Use extend to add a list to another list, append to add a element to a list.

```
list1.extend(input_list)
list1.append('5')
list1.append('6')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
import copy

list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
input_list = ['5', '6']

output = []
for e in input_list:
    l = copy.copy(list1)
    l.append(e)
    output.append(l)

print(output)
```

Result

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6']]
```

The trick is `copy()` to make a new list

Comment: A much better way to create a copy of `list1` is t simply say `list1[:]`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternitive to @Kenji's soultion, you could use a simple one-liner:

```
res = [list1+[i] for i in input_list]
```

Full program:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
input_list = ['5', '6']

res = [list1+[i] for i in input_list]
print(res) # prints: [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6']]
```